# Safely Filtering CALL_PRIVILEGED

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has an intent filter that makes phone calls via an alternative method (Think Skype, but not). As such it has an intent filter that intercepts Intent.CALL_PRIVILEGED.

The problem? I don't actually want to handle calls to 911. I don't want to get in their way. I want them going to the regular phone app.

My life would easier if the dialer system apps only used the CALL_PRIVILEGED intent for 911 calls, but they seem to use it for all calls which from my POV, seems to defeat the purpose of having the intent.

But they don't.

And I don't believe I can declare the intent filter with an piece of XML like:

```
 <data android:scheme="!tel:911"/>
```

So as to avoid the 911 call...

Which brings me to the point of wanting to write into my app a piece of code that says, "Oh, that's a call for 911, let me send it to the Real Phone Activity. But I can't, as my app isn't a system app, and as such isn't allowed to issue it's own Intent for CALL_PRIVILEGED in order to dial 911 itself.

Is there any way around this issue? Or does Skype have the same problem too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre apparently supposed to do this via a Broadcast Receiver.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/05/handling-phone-call-requests-right-way.html